# when does windows connect to the internet?

Tags: windows, startup, boot, internet-connection

I want to create an app which sends some data on boot to a server. Should I write a service or wait till that user logs in, creating a registry key at Run. I think that windows connects to the internet after log in, but I am not sure.

Comment: It completely depends on what kind of connection you have.

Comment: You cannot know for sure when Windows is going to be connected to the internet. You need add a hook with whatever language you are using and detect when the computer is online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Network Awareness in Windows XP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700657%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

[Network Awareness in Windows Vista and Windows 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264321%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

I believe the Vista/7 implementation is just using a request to a web site setup by Microsoft to determine if the web site is reachable.